# ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U12'), dtype('<U12')) -> dtype('<U12')

Tags: python, numpy

**Well i am trying to run some tests using lines from a test.txt file and importing them into numpy arrays in order to do some calculations with them.However after i finished writing my code it displayed the error message presented in the title.**

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np 

with open('test.txt', 'r')  as f:
      f_contents = np.array([f.readline()])

      print(f_contents)

      a = f_contents 

      f_contents = np.array([f.readline()])

      print(f_contents)

      b = f_contents

      print(a+b)
```

The line

```
print(a+b)
```

Is what generates the error message: numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype(' dtype('

Edit: I am new to coding and selftaught so excuse any logical errors or crude coding style

Comment: What kind of data does your text file contain? A preview would be nice.

Comment: So you have printed `f_contents`.  What does it look like?  The error indicates that it's a list of strings (see the quotes?).  You can't add strings arrays.  You need numeric arrays.  Don't skip basic `numpy` introductions.

Comment: @amzon-ex It was a txt file with 2 rows of numbers

Comment: @hpaulj You were right i read more about numpy and i used the np.genfromtxt command and i am almost done with my programm! Though i want to thank you for your time to help